# Vscode task & emscripten

Tags: visual-studio-code, emscripten, webassembly, vscode-tasks

I've created a custom task that compile my "C" files with emscripten, but the output files are saved at the root of my workspace.
  I would like to change this, so the compiled files are saved in the same directory as my input js file

My task.json file:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"command": "echo",
"args": ["Hello World"],
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Emscripten + HTML",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "emcc ${file} -o ${fileBasename}.html" 
    },
    {
        "taskName": "Emscripten + Webassemby + html",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "emcc ${file} -s WASM=1 -o ${fileBasename}.html"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in output file name instead of `${fileBasename}.html`

use `${fileDirname}/${fileBasename}.htm`

Comment: Yes that is the solution, I realised 5 minutes after I asked this question. Thanks